# zsh comments nearly invisible on command-line

Tags: zsh, x-resources, color-management, suckless-terminal

When typing comments into the command-line in zsh, the commented text appears nearly invisible. I use the st terminal ([Luke Smith's fork](https://github.com/lukesmithxyz/st)), which pulls on my `.Xresources` for setting colors and it seems that comments get set to `color0`. This is an issue because the background color of the terminal is also set by `color0`, meaning that the comment color always matches the background, and thus, is always invisible (I can kind of see it because my terminal background is slightly transparent). Any ideas on how to fix this? Here's what the coloring looks like:

[image: my terminal coloring]

Edit: I'm using [zsh-syntax-highlighting](https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh-syntax-highlighting) (through oh-my-zsh).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've actually figured out the solution--thanks for pointing me towards my syntax highlighter! I just needed to go into zsh-syntax-highlighting's main highlighter and change the values for `ZSH_HIGHLIGHT_STYLES[comment]`.

Comment: So to actually change the font color, you can put e.g. `ZSH_HIGHLIGHT_STYLES[comment]="fg=#eeeeee"` into your zshrc file